# Отключить fullpage при включенном меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage

ребят вопрос такой
есть 2 кода js, 1 - это меню второй это плагин fullpage.

Как мне сделать что бы при открытом меню, fullpage отключался или не было возможности скроллить страницу. Если закрыл меню собственно включался и была возможно скроллить.

js тут
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

```js
var w = $(window).width(),
    h = $(window).height();
  //$('section').width(w);
  $('sectdion').height(h);
  $('menu .container').height(h - 60);
  $('body').prepend('<div id="overlay">');
    

  $('#menu').click(function() {
    $('html').addClass('active');
   
  });
  $('#close-menu').click(function() {
    $('html').removeClass('active');
  });
  $('#overlay').click(function() {
    $('html').removeClass('active');
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width(),
      h = $(window).height();
    //$('section').width(w);
    $('secdtion').height(h);
    $('menu .container').height(h - 60);
  });

});


$('#fullpage').fullpage({
   scrollOverflow: true,
    scrollOverflowReset: true,
 
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Добавьте html как минимум.

Comment: Вешать overflow: hidden; на body при наведении на меню и убирать, когда мышка с меню ушла

Comment: пробовал я overflow ставить, не работает то что нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вынести fullpage в функцию.

```
function creatFullPage() {
        $('.init-fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: false,
            scrollingSpeed: 500,
        });
    }
```

Во-вторых вызвать функцию по умолчанию

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   creatFullPage();
});
```

А дальше делать проверку на событие клика по меню

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  creatFullPage();

  var addCl = true;
  $('selector').bind('click', function () {
    if (addCl) {
         addCl = false;
         $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all'); //отключаем плагим
    } else if(!addCl) {
        addCl = true;
        creatFullPage();
    } 
  });

});
```

Вот и все.